# How can i use the UI object from MainActivity to other activity?

Tags: android, object, user-interface

I am trying to write a code in Android to use the UI object from my MainActivity to other activity.

I am trying to say is  , i want to print a text in other activity using the TextView object from MainActivity. Please go through the below code which will make you understand properly about my requirement.

**MyCode :**

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mytestui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

TextView txt;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);


} }
```

**Demo.java**

```
package com.example.mytestui;

import android.app.Activity;

public class DemoUI extends Activity
{


    // How can i use the TextView object from MainActivity to print a text ? //


}
```

Please go through my above code , please suggest me , how can i do this ?

Comment: u cannot pass UI widget but pass data and create new instance in next activity

Comment: just use `Bundle` to store your parameters

Comment: If you start DEMOUI Activity from MainActivity, you can startActivityFromResult and set the text when returns to MainActivity.

Comment: I got the solution .... i am updating my post now ...

Comment: Google before asking.

Comment: why to Google always ... that i know properly ... i got some doubt so i asked  but i solved the question on myself ....

Comment: So you all go through my post Answer .... you can get , what i wanted to solve.

Comment: can you say your purpose,maybe better way exist!!! because at the same time just one activity user can see,so you can start demo activity for result

Comment: Your posted answer must also be DOWNVOTED...

Comment: What the hell you are talking , i solved it , what the reason to Downvoted , can't we have enthusiasm to research more about the Android coding and to do some more extra stuff ...

Comment: "Solved it" in a Bad manner, we are here to guide to the right path.

Answer (score 2):

You Can trigger the DemoUI from your Main Activity using an intent and you can pass the values as an extras.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(DemoUI.class);
i.putExtra("textValue", txt);
startActivity(intent);
```

Then in DemoUI Activty OnCreate, you can retrieve the value using

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
String textVal = extras.getString("textValue");
```

Comment: I don't want to pass the textValue , how can I pass the text object to other activity?

Answer (score -3):

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mytestui;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.app.Activity;


public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{

  public static TextView txt;

  DemoUI du = new DemoUI();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);

    du.ui();


} }
```

**Demo.java**

```
package com.example.mytestui;

import android.app.Activity;

public class DemoUI extends Activity
{


  public void ui()
  {

      MainActivity.txt.setText("Hello All");

  }}
```

Comment: You should avoid making the instance of a class extending Activity, its not a best practice, you should try using Bundle to pass data b/w activities.

Comment: "Not best practice" is pretty understating -- it's an abomination.